# Вопрос по поводу ввода: заменить строковую константу в коде на пользовательский ввод

Tags: python

Можно ли в этом коде самому задавать нужные значения?Вместо 'dfR56*Jvn' из клавиатуры вводить не изменяя в самом коде

```
import re
a=re.findall('[a-z]','dfR56*Jvn')
print (len(a))
```

Comment: как понимать нужные значения?

Comment: Самому вводить строку в которой нужно искать малые буквы

Answer (score 2):

Используйте просто ввод данных через `input()`

```
import re
a = re.findall('[a-zа-я]', input(""))
print(len(a))
```

Реализация через список

```
import re
a = list(filter(None, list(map(lambda x: re.findall('[a-zа-я]', x), list(input())))))
print(len(a))
```

[Проверка](https://repl.it/@Cmertho/AltruisticNavyblueDeal)

```
Hello World Привет Мир
15
```

Comment: Можно ли список присвоить также вместо input("")?

Comment: @Oziwek да можно